# .Net Core Entity Framework FromSqlRaw perform insert and return Identity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am doing an Asp.Net Core Application and I am using Entity Framework to performs Select, Insert and Update to the database.

I am using

```
_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(" insert into TEST3( Field) Values ('ok')");
```

and works fine...

But I need to retrieve the `@@Identity` generated. So I run

```
query = "insert into TEST3( Field) Values ('ok'); Select @@IDENTITY as Id;"
T aa = await _dbContext.Set<T>().FromSqlRaw(query).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

T is a Model to get the Id

```
 public class InsertModel
    {
        [Key]
        public Int32 Id{ get; set; }
    }
```

I have this error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: ''FromSql' or 'SqlQuery' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.'
```

How can I perform the insert and return the ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with ExecuteSqlRaw and an output parameter.

```
var pId = new SqlParameter("@rv", SqlDbType.Int);
pId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(" insert into TEST3( Field) Values ('ok'); set @id = scope_identity();", pId);
var id = (int)pId.Value;
```